# How to separate two user's home directory in to different partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, encryption, users, disk

I have /home directory in the separate partition. But, I have two users in my system. I want to create a separate partition for one of these user.

**Like**
partition1 : /home
partition2 : /home/user1

Partition1 for all user except user1. user1's data will be stored in partiton2(/home/user1).
I will keep username same for partition mounting point so it should not affect any application and configuration.

1. If I divide current home partition into two partitions.
2. Copy all /home/user1 data into newly created partition2.
3. And change mount point of partition2 to /home/user1.

Will it work?
Or any other better way to do it?
Thanks

Purpose behind doing this is, I want to encrypt one user's partition.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) for this.

The only difference; you will be mounting your new partition as you say in 3.